# Modules over PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

Let $a$ and $b$ be two nonzero elements of a PID $R$. Prove that direct sum $R/aR\oplus R/bR$ is isomorphic to the direct sum $R/cR\oplus R/dR$, where $c=\mathrm{lcm(a,b)}$, $d=\gcd(a,b)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The [structure theorem for modules over a PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain) gives a **canonical form** for finitely generated torsion modules.  Here you have two finitely generated torsion modules, say $T_1$ and $T_2$, which you want to show are isomorphic, but neither one is (necessarily) in canonical form.  So the natural first thing to do is...